# How to multiply a value each month?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started taking classes of python and I am trying to make a code in where the value of the first month = 1 and multiply its value by 2 next month, and then by 3 next month, and 2 next month and so on. Until it reaches 6 months. I am using this code but it only gives me Month 1 = 1 which is the initial value.

```
P = 1
count = 12

print ("month 1: ",P)

for month in range(count-1):

    if month %2 == 0:
        P = P*2 
    else:
        P = P*3

print:("month", month+2 ,":",P)
```

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below one of the answers, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer). Although the question was closed (New answers not allowed), you can still reward an answer that was helpful to you, if any. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
print:("month", month+2 ,":",P)
```

to

```
print("month", month+2 ,":",P)
```

I'm not sure why python didn't complain about the colon.  You can actually put anything there

```
weird: ("month", month+2 ,":",P)
```

And it won't complain. Awesome mistake, thanks!

Comment: It actually worked without the colon! but in the results it just shows month 1=1, month 12=15552. Is there a way that I can make it to show month 2,3,4,5, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `range(count-1)` will return numbers between 0 and 11 (the last number is non-inclusive)

Your logic could be like this:

(a) A counter that starts at 1 (`cnt`)
(b) A loop that watches for the counter to reach 6, then exits
(c) A running total (`month_val` or some such)

```
cnt = 1
month_val = 1
while cnt < 7:
   month_val = month_val * cnt
   print(month_val)
   cnt += 1
```

The above assumes that you retain the new value of `month_num` -- but re-reading your question, you might just want to print the values 1 to 6, in which case the `month_num` value should just remain 1 all the time:

```
cnt = 1
month_val = 1
while cnt < 7:
   print(month_val * cnt)
   cnt += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary for your problem like

```
month_values={}
for i in range(1,7):
    if i == 1:
        month_values['Month'+str(i)]=1
    elif i%2 == 0:
        month_values['Month'+str(i)]=i*2
    elif i%2 == 1:
       month_values['Month'+str(i)]=i*3

print(month_values)
```

prints
    {'Month1': 1, 'Month2': 4, 'Month3': 9, 'Month4': 8, 'Month5': 15, 'Month6': 12}